I'm receiving an 'Invalid Syntax Error' for the dict I have in Python
I am creating a game for a project I'm working on using Python. Everything looks right and matches the example I was given to use but I am still getting an Invalid Syntax Error and it won't run my code until it is fixed.
rooms = {
    'Start': {'East': 'Living Room', 'item': 'Key'},
    'Living Room': {'South': 'Bathroom', 'item': 'Towel'},
    'Bathroom': {'East': 'Guest Room', 'item': 'Journal'},
    'Guest Room': {'North': 'Green Room' 'item':'Journal'},
    'Green Room': {'North': 'Master Bedroom', 'Villain'},
    'Master Bedroom': {'North': 'Mud Room', 'item': 'Shoes'},
    'Mudroom': {'West': 'Kitchen' 'item': 'Knife'}}

This is my current dict that I am trying and it is showing the error on the 3rd line. I have tried lining it up with the first row and making sure all of the parenthesis are where they need to be and I am still getting the error code.

On this line:
'Green Room': {'North': 'Master Bedroom', 'Villain'},

You don't have the key (or value) for 'Villain'. You also don't have a comma before 'item' on these lines:
'Guest Room': {'North': 'Green Room' 'item':'Journal'}

'Mudroom': {'West': 'Kitchen' 'item': 'Knife'}

